# Problem about getting keys JSON multi class

Tags: javascript, json

I has some problem about JSON and JavaScript because i just a beginner about this.
Now i try to `foreach` the all `keys["name"]` of this json

```
var l = [{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "Scan",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "radiogroup",
     "name": "Gender",
     "title": "Gender",
     "choices": [
      "Male",
      "Female"
     ]
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "Name",
     "title": "Name"
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "Age",
     "inputType": "number"
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "E-mail",
     "title": "E-mail",
     "validators": [
      {
       "type": "email"
      }
     ],
     "inputType": "email"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Q",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "radiogroup",
     "name": "What Country Food you like?",
     "choices": [
      "Thailand",
      "Japan",
      "Italy"
     ],
     "colCount": 3
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "What is your favorite food",
     "visibleIf": "{What Country Food you like?} notempty"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}];
```

I try to use this

```
    l.forEach(function(element) {
         console.log(element);       
});
```

but i getting just 2 Arrays in console.log

```
0:Array[name:"Scan", element:Array(4)}
1:Array[name:"Q", element:Array(2)}
```

All i need is `keys["name"]` look like this

```
(Scan, Name, Age, Gender, E-mail, "What Country Food you like?", "What is your favorite food")
```

Comment: and why no `Gender` which is the value of name property as well?

Comment: i just forgot i will edit now. thank you.

Comment: and why not `Q` which is a value of `name` property as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i got my answer with my self 
thank everyone

```
l[0].pages[0].elements[0];
```